# PHP implode array issues

Tags: php, arrays, implode

Newbie technical difficulty here.
Hope I can explain this clearly.
in My DB, I have snFreq, snFreq2, snFreqIV, snFreqTube, snFreqTrach, snFreqCath, snFreqWound, and snFreqOstomy.
I wrote an isset to check each column if data exist, then make a variable with preset text.
After all the checkpoints, I wanted to include this in a phrase, but don't want to include the "0" data. For some reason my output is still showing multiple commas with blank data.
Here's an example output:
SN FREQUENCY/DURATION: QD X 60 DAYS + 2 PRN VISITS FOR IV COMPLICATIONS, TUBE FEEDING COMPLICATIONS, , , , < = with extra commas?
In my DB:
snFreq = QD X 60 DAYS, snFreq2 = 1, snFreqIV = 1, and snFreqTube = 1, the rest are Null.

```
    if(isset($rowPlanOfCare['snFreq'])){$snFreq = "SN FREQUENCY/DURATION: " . $rowPlanOfCare['snFreq'];}
    if(isset($rowPlanOfCare['snFreq2'])){$snFreq2 = " + 2 PRN VISITS FOR ";}
    if(isset($rowPlanOfCare['snFreqIV'])){$snFreqIV = "IV COMPLICATIONS";}
    if(isset($rowPlanOfCare['snFreqTube'])){$snFreqTube = "TUBE FEEDING COMPLICATIONS";}
    if(isset($rowPlanOfCare['snFreqTrach'])){$snFreqTrach = "TRACHEOSTOMY CARE COMPLICATIONS";}
    if(isset($rowPlanOfCare['snFreqCath'])){$snFreqCath = "CATHETER CARE COMPLICATIONS";}
    if(isset($rowPlanOfCare['snFreqWound'])){$snFreqWound = "WOUND CARE COMPLICATIONS";}
    if(isset($rowPlanOfCare['snFreqOstomy'])){$snFreqOstomy = "OSTOMY CARE COMPLICATIONS";}
    $snFrequency = $snFreq . $snFreq2 . implode(", ",array($snFreqIV, $snFreqTube, $snFreqTrach, $snFreqCath, $snFreqWound, $snFreqOstomy)) . "\n \n ";
```

Final Output should only show: SN FREQUENCY/DURATION: QD X 60 DAYS + 2 PRN VISITS FOR IV COMPLICATIONS, TUBE FEEDING COMPLICATIONS < == without the other commas.

I hope you can help me out with this issues. Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: isset is not the same as empty()

Comment: `if (isset($rowPlanOfCare['snFreqOstomy']) && $rowPlanOfCare['snFreqOstomy'] !=" "))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
 $snFrequency = $snFreq . $snFreq2 . implode(", ",array_filter(array($snFreqIV, $snFreqTube, $snFreqTrach, $snFreqCath, $snFreqWound, $snFreqOstomy))) . "\n \n ";
```